# How to stop DNS attack in dns server

Tags: dns

My DNS server is receiving hundreds of query request in every minutes from unknown users.

How can I stop this?

Comment: What software are you using for DNS ?
Are these repeated requests from a the same group of ip addresses (if so we can use iptables to restrict number of connections) ?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and tell us i) which version of Ubuntu ii) which DNS server iii) give us an example of a log file showing these attempts iv) explain what kind of network you are running, what is this server serving?

Answer (score 4):

**Step 1:** Don't run a public DNS server. Use a hosted solution. I've just [been over the reasons why](https://askubuntu.com/a/476809/449) with another user. There's no decent reason for running your own IMO, at least not for external production hosting.

---

There doesn't need to be a step 2 but if you're really determined, [your DNS server might be being used to contribute to a DDoS attack](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/keep-dns-servers-from-contributing-to-a-ddos-attack/) on another host. DNS servers will recurse to answer a query and this can cause allow massive traffic swarms from DNS servers. I'm saying you could inadvertantly be part of that swarm.

Fixing it is simple enough: don't run a DNS server or [disable external recursion](https://askubuntu.com/questions/170728/how-to-disable-external-dns-recursion).